# Will this regex for email work for all emails?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, email-validation

I am looking to improve my regex skills for use in my Ruby programming.
I have come up with the matcher below for emails.
Can it be improved?  Will it work for all email addresses?
Is the mailto: bit ok?

```
/(mailto:)*\w+@\w+.[A-z]+.[A-z]{2,4}/
```

It matches addresses like

```
bob@test.com
bob_smith@test.com
bob_smith@prefix.test.com
abc@xyz.co.uk
mailto:fred@test.com
```

Comment: It won't work for special or non-latin characters, such as nøx@nåx.dk

Comment: You do realize that `[mailto:]*` means "zero or more characters from the set {`:`, `a`, `i`, `l`, `m`, `o`, `t`}"?

Comment: good point ruakh, thyat's why I posted this.  Do you know how it be improved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Comment: it own't match filters, `bob+SO@test.com`

Comment: How about `(mailto:)*\w+@\w+.[A-z]+.[A-z]{2,4}` ?

Comment: What is your intent? To see if an email only matches your pattern? Or, is it to see if it is a valid address? The second is a much more difficult question, because an email address might match your pattern and still not be real. The simplest answer is to try sending a message to the address, asking the human at the other end to respond. Doing that answers your question too, along with other questions you'll probably want answered in subsequent steps.

Comment: Mathletics, I don't get that, sorry.  I don't want to allow a +.  Please expand on your comment for clarity "it own't match filters" means something to you but nothing to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tin Man - sorry to repeat my first line, but "I am looking to improve my regex skills for use in my Ruby programming."

Comment: Actually you **do** want to allow a `+` as that's perfectly valid in an email address; you're also missing `bob.smith@pan-cakes.com`. And `\w+` isn't what you want for a host name, find and study the appropriate RFCs or better, practice your regex skills on something less complicated.

Comment: Could the folks being negative find some other questions to comment on please.  I am looking for help with regexp's not opinions about why I am using them, if I am using them, if it's appropriate, etc.  Those are great questions but not the question I am asking.  I am looking for help with the immediate task at hand, not the philosophy or reasoning behind it.

Comment: Hi mu, I didn't know that a + was valid.  Thank You.

Comment: junky: if you're talking about the RFC "spec" for email addresses, then ANY character is valid _so long as it is escaped properly_ - thus, `"The@night;train.2%katmandu\ *(A#story!)@some.server.gift-horse.justified.BigBuilding.museum` is a valid email address according to the RFC (as far as I know) - most servers have more restrictive rules, though.

Comment: As for "filters", you can learn more about how an email address can be structured, including "tags" (or filters) on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags)

Comment: Finally, the best site I know of for learning regex in general is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: NO. not ALL emails can be checked by regex. there's a thread somewhere here on SO, where they explain this much better than i could if i attempted. I *think* the only way to check if email is really an email is to contact the mail server and enquire whether user account exists.

please, have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373724/81520

Comment: Good point.  However most large sites that I sign up to check format.